# REST API from Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on usecase where i have to read (id , token and type values delimited with pipe )from kafka topic using spark streaming job.
Using the above values, i have to make rest api call to pull data belongs to id.

I am using below code which i am able to get the data in json format.

```
 val httpget = new HttpGet("///////");
    val httpParams = httpClient.getParams
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,timeoutConnection)
    val httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpget)

    println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode)
     val entity = httpResponse.getEntity()
    var content = ""
    if (entity != null) {
      val inputStream = entity.getContent()
      content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).getLines.mkString
      inputStream.close
    }
```

My problem here is using this logic in dStream.foreachRDD() block  and parsing the json content effectively.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is Spark Streaming using a HTTP GET?

Comment: like i said i get the real time data into kafka topic.The data in kafka includes only id of users. Using this id i have to make rest api call to get record of the user.

Comment: I think you need to use `DStream.map`, then to "augment" your data. `foreachRDD` is only when you want to collect all the data